# Are these two functions in $C^{\infty}$?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-derivative

Define the function $h(x)$ by setting $h(x) = e^{-1/x^2}$ if $x>0$ and $0$ if $x \leq 0$.

1. My question is how can I show $h(x)$ is in $C^{\infty}$?
2. Let $\| \mathbf{x} \| = \max_{i=1,2} | x_i |$. Then is 
   $h(\| \cdot\|) : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ in $C^{\infty}$ as well?

Comment: Can you generalize $\frac{d^n}{dx^n} (e^{f(x)})$? If so, will it continuous on $(0,\infty)$ for $f(x) = -\frac{1}{x^2}$? Will it approach $0$ as $x \to 0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only concern is at zero. All you need to do is show that all derivatives exist, and are zero, by considering the left and right derivatives.

For your question 2, remember that a two-variable function is differentiable at a point if both partial derivatives are continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Hint for 2. Suppose $a>0.$ For $y>0,$ the function at $(a,a+y)$ equals $e^{-1/(a+y)^2}.$ But for $y<0$ the function is just the constant $e^{-1/a^2}.$ That doesn't look good for the existence of partial derivatives at $(a,a).$